# How to get the values from dummy table to variables?

Tags: postgresql

```
(SELECT SUBSTRING(TO_CHAR(current_timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh12:mi:ss AM'),21,2)),
                            current_date ,
                            current_date - INTERVAL '1' DAYS, 
                            to_char(current_date,'Day') into 
                            vs_current_ampm,
                            vd_current_dt,
                            vd_prev_dt, 
                            vl_day;
```

Comment: You might need to use a procedure/function for that case. You can create a cursor and then try to read data from that.

Comment: Please check the cursors documentation for the same: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/plpgsql-cursors.html

Comment: You need a single into and it will hold the first matching record. Reading the values from that variable and copying into other variables is what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

The forementioned query has a minor syntax error, i.e., an extra `)` after `21,2`.
I have changed that and the below query works fine.

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(TO_CHAR(current_timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh12:mi:ss AM'),21,2),
    current_date , current_date - INTERVAL '1' DAYS, 
    to_char(current_date,'Day');
```

If you would like to use the results in another place, you might need to use a cursor as I mentioned in the comments.

Check the documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/plpgsql-cursors.html).